# What is the difference between an id and an objectId for parse.com

Tags: javascript, mongodb, parse-platform

This has caused a bit of a headache for me because I can't anticipate when Parse.com intends to return an object with an `objectId` property or an object with an `id` property. It's thrown me off a few times and it prolongs my debugging process.

Does anyone have an idea as to why they have these two names for the same thing on Parse.com?

**EDIT** Here is a screenshot for reference.

The first `console.log` invokes `Parse.User.current()`. The second and third are invoked by an API call to my two custom classes `MenuItem` and `Address`.

[image]

Perhaps this is just an inconsistency between the Parse libraries and the Parse JS API?

Comment: `objectId` is the only native id that parse uses. Where are you seeing this `id`?

Comment: I think the pattern I'm seeing is that the property is called `id` when there is only one object returned. For instance, `Parse.User.current()` returns an object with an `id` property and another object property called `attributes` for all the other columns.

Comment: I took another look at the API and Users doesn't have an id field (https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#users). The only part of the API that involves an id field is the authdata when authenticating with facebook/twitter/etc. in that case id is the facebook id and similar.

Comment: I added a screenshot of my console log. I seem to get `id` when I use the Parse.com SDK.

Comment: Last question, did you use the Parse javascript library for all those calls? The first looks like a library call, while the last 2 seem like REST requests.

Comment: In my `Cloud Code`, I use the JS SDK, instead of RESTful calls. So things like my order processing (it's a food delivery app) create and return objects using the SDK, since I have to process the transaction on Cloud Code. However, in my local client, I use RESTful calls for everything except retrieving the current user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quirk of the Parse javascript library; it does a transform on the raw JSON data returned by the API, which remaps `objectId` to `id`. This means that *all* objects you get using the javascript library should use `id`.

This is different from the raw REST API since that responds with `objectId`.

Both are exactly the same value-wise and behaviour-wise, they just have different names.

Comment: Go figure haha. Thank you for your help!